# Handling Windows Popup like Save As, Choose File, Direct UI HWND InternetExplorer Download Strip....When System is Locked

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

To Handle all the Windows Popup i'd followed three different ways but none of them works when the system is locked, Kindly help me with this

With the Help of UIAutomationClient.dll,UIAutomationClientsideProviders.dll,UIAutomationProvider.dll,UIAutomationTypes.dll

```
using System.Windows.Automation;

AutomationElement ieElement = AutomationElement.FromHandle((IntPtr)ieObj.HWND);//Save As popup handle for Popups

            AutomationElement saveElement = ReturnRequiredElement(ieElement, "Save", "Name");
            if (saveElement.Current.Name.Equals("Save"))
            {
                var invokePattern = saveElement.GetCurrentPattern(InvokePattern.Pattern) as InvokePattern;
                invokePattern.Invoke();
            }
```

With the Help of InputSimulator

```
using WindowsInput;

InputSimulator.SimulateModifiedKeyStroke(VirtualKeyCode.MENU, VirtualKeyCode.VK_S);
```

With SendKeys

```
SendKeys.SendWait("^+{S}");
```

You know while running the scheduler or a batch process automation in a system we can't expect that should be active always, especially in servers

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note : All the above codes works fine when the System or Desktop is Active